# simulate click on <a> inside of a <li>

Tags: jquery

I have an `<a>` tag inside a `<li>` tag, and I want the `<a>` inside it to be clicked when the `<li>` is clicked.

I tried the following:

```
$('li.level2').click(function() {
        $( $(this) +' a').click();
    });
```

but I get an error saying "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]".

Comment: can you add a JSFiddle?

Comment: Why not simply make your li as big as your a?

Answer (score 3):

To find a link within the element that was clicked, use `find` (or for just immediate children of the element, `children`):

```
$('li.level2').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() !== "A") {
        $(this).find('a').click(); // Or $(this).children('a').click();
    }
});
```

Note that I've filtered out events that originate with the anchor, so it doesn't recurse.

But there's also a CSS solution: You can make the anchor *fill* the list item by changing it to `display: block` (depending on how your list is styled).

---

If the goal is to *follow* the link, then here's how you can do that with JavaScript (e.g., if you don't want to fill the `li` with the link using CSS):

```
// Clicking the `li` clicks the link
$('li.level2').click(function(e) {
    var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href'); // Or .children
    if (url) {
        window.location = url;
    }
});

// Clicking the link stops propagation (so the li doesn't see it)
$('li.level2 a').click(function(e) { // Or `$('li.level2 > a')... for just immediately children
      e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/afIjAVO/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/afIjAVO/1/edit)

Comment: Now nothing happens :( (appreciate the effort though)

Comment: @OlliccaMindstorm: This shouldn't be complicated. What do you want to have happen when the anchor is clicked, and what do you want to have happen when the list item is clicked?

Comment: There is <a> inside <li>, I want when <li> is clicked to behave like <a> inside of it was clicked (to save me the trouble of restyling the damn thing).

Comment: Screw it, I will just restyle it. Thanks though.

Comment: @OlliccaMindstorm: But what do you want to have happen when the link is clicked? Follow the link?

Comment: Yea, it's not necessary anymore though.

Comment: `.children` is the better option here, because you don't want the click on possible submenu links as well. And also `li.level2 > a` then.

Comment: @BramVanroy: It may be, yes, depending on the structure.